# Cannot use scaffolding to create controller using EF Core 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am using EF Core 6 with .NET 6. I have separated my models, dbcontext and controllers into separate projects in the same solution. I have the same version of all the required nuget packages installed in all of the projects even though I don't think they are necessary in some (even without the bloat I receive the same error).

When trying to create a controller using the scaffolding by selecting add MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework, I get the following error:

[image: Error Message]

Here are the settings I'm using:

[image: Settings selected when scaffolding]

Here is my `DbContext` class. Even when removing the override on the `OnModelCreating` method I still receive the issue. I have also cleared my NuGet package manager cache several times. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WMS.Models;

namespace WMS.DataAccess
{
    public class ApplicationDBContext :DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderHeader>()
                .HasKey(a => new { a.Order, a.ReleaseNumber });

            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
                .HasKey(b => new { b.Order, b.ReleaseNumber });

            modelBuilder.Entity<OrderDetail>()
                .HasOne(b => b.OrderHeader)
                .WithMany(a => a.OrderDetails)
                .HasForeignKey(b => new { b.Order, b.ReleaseNumber });
        }

        public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<OrderHeader> OrderHeaders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Item` model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WMS.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public int Weight   { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my solution explorer for an overview

[image: Solution Explorer]

wms nuget packages

[image: Packages for WMS project]

WMS.DataAccess packages

[image: WMS.DataAccess Packages]

WMS.Models packages

[image: WMS.Models Packages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I'm not sure what exactly fixed it but the issue is resolved. I ended up upgrading the visualstudio.web.codegeneration.design package to 6.0.13 (which I had already tried more than once) after I uninstalled visual studio and reinstalled it and then it finally worked. I decided to uninstall visual studio after realizing that my scaffolding was broken in every project I had not just this one.